# Why draw dash line on a Canvas not working?

Tags: android, canvas

Why does the following code work on Pixel 2, but does not work on Samsung Note 8?

```
linePaint.let { paint ->
     paint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
     paint.color = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.red)
     paint.strokeWidth = 10
     paint.pathEffect = DashPathEffect(floatArrayOf(10, 20), 0f)
}

canvas.drawLine(0, canvas.height / 2, canvas.width, canvas.height / 2, linePaint)
```

I saw tips to use `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"`, but it doesn’t work because performance problems appear

Comment: the same problem :-(

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following code to the constructor method:

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }
```

Answer to reference **Ahmed Abdelsalam**

Answer (score -2):

On your View class, you should disable hardware acceleration. This will enable you draw dotted and dashed lines

You can do this by:

```
setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```